# Could I avoid interrupting Java thread again, when I know that it will terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling, java-threads

I have read all the related material around thread interruptions in Java and their contribution as a mechanism to support gracefully cancellable tasks. However, I have a very specific case, where I think it makes sense (against all suggestions) to neither re-throw the InterruptedException nor set the interrupted status.

So, let's say I am implementing a retrying mechanism over a method. Let's say the method is:

```
...
public String call(String request) {
    return "Hello " + request;
}
...
```

I am implementing the retrying, by wrapping this method with another method, that catches any Exception thrown by this method, sleeping for a specific interval and then retrying. The related code is:

```
public String wrapperCall(String request) {
    ...
    try {
        call(request);
    } catch(Exception exception){ 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            throw new MaxRetryException("Stopped retrying due to interruption");
        }

    }
    ...
}
```

I believe that in this case I can avoid both re-throwing the InterruptedException or setting the interrupted status on the thread, because:

- The call will fail with the MaxRetryException, which is a RuntimeException anyway, so this thread will terminate. The call of this method will be done as part of a web server request, so there is no reason to think about cancellability.
- There is no ExecutorService that will need to be informed, so that it perform cancelling processes or resource cleaning

Obviously, I know that ideally I should follow the suggested principle to be covered against all possible uses of this method. However, for other practical reasons, I cannot do it. So, I am trying to understand what are the risks of not doing it.

**Am I right in thinking that this case is an exception, where avoiding propagating the interrupted status upwards will not create any issue ?**

*UPDATE 1: To provide some more context, the reason I could not set the interrupt status was the [failure of Jacoco to generate some reports](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/64). This seems to be due to a JDK [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154017). I finally managed to set the interrupt status and avoid the Jacoco failure, by resetting the interrupt status in all the relevant unit tests. However, the question still remains if there is a need for the  interrupt to be set in this context and who could benefit from it, besides just setting it for the sake of good order.*

Comment: you already created an issue, that is to deal in run time (the runtime exception) with a situation created in compile time (a thread interruption)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by a situation created in "compile time". As I said, in this context, this call performs just a simple RPC. There is no interrupt triggered by my code, so I think that any interrupt caused can be considered a pure RuntimeException.

Comment: an `interrupt()` call, if any, is done in compile time. A thread is not interrupted in run time (unless you catch a runtime exception and then interrupts a thread, but i guess it's hardly the case)

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, JVM will never try to interrupt a sleeping thread at runtime, such as for exceptional cases, like not enough memory, threads etc. If yes, then given that I don't perform any multi-threading in this context and I trigger no interrupts, then it's safe to assume that this sleep() will never be interrupted, right ?

Comment: as far as i know yes, jvm won't deliberately interrupt a thread, be it running or sleeping. However, mind that a 3rd party library can. If a grave problem arises (e.g. hardware failure, out of memory) then probably an `Error` will be raised, and in this case the app is helpless

Comment: yes, i think you can assume that sleep will never be interrupted, and even if it is, java allows you to ignore the interruption, that is, catch the exception, do nothing and go on